# IdentityServer 4 on Azure Can we secure its endpoints using Azure API gateway

Tags: azure, identityserver4, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

We have created our own IdentityServer4 and deployed it on App Services in azure.
I also have few apis that are protected by API gateway for me. 
Can i PUT IdentityServer4 endpoints secured by API gateway?
If yes, how? Do i need to configure some policy in gateway?
Front end is Mobile application and user register/ login using username/ pwd following ROPC Flow. I feel this will also change instead of IdentityServer4 TokenEnpoint i will hit API gateway with user/pwd in header right?
The api gateay will now hit IdentityServer4 using configured policy and get access_token?

Comment: Why are you putting IdentityServer behind Api Gateway?

Comment: so we have only 1 endpoint and also DDOS attacks etc gateway can take care